# BOM/OPL parts help before PCB fab

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly, bom, fabrication

I am completing my first official PCB project.  I am outsourcing the PCB fab to Seeeed Studio.  I was wondering if any of you might be able to shed some light on my issue.
I am using their PCB assembly service with OPL parts.  I am using Eagle cad with Seeed Studio's eagle cad OPL parts libraries.  Upon uploading the gerbers I was asked to also upload (or fill out their online form) a BOM file for the OPL parts.
My issue is the eagle cad OPL parts libraries do not seem to match up perfectly with there online listings of OPL parts, or at least it is nearly impossible to find any relation among about 50% of the parts.

Has anyone dealt with this before?

Here is the link to their main wiki page regarding this
http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Open_parts_library#Connector
and also their main home web page regarding this
http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/OPLopen-parts-library-catalog-c-136_138/?ref=side

I am specifically having trouble with figuring out how to fill out there BOM file with the specified parts and values because I cannot relate the parts in the eagle cad libraries with the parts I am finding in there physical listings.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Have you tried exporting a BOM straight from Eagle?

Comment: I didn't realize you could do that at first, but the bom from eagle does not have XYRS data (component placement), after some further research, I found .ulp scripts from advanced circuits and another fab house that was able to generate appropriate XYRS data.  When I get home if I remember I will post my findings for others

Comment: Please do, this site lives off good answers :)

Comment: @scarlso9 -- post your findings and I'll upvote them :)

Comment: I've been trying to find them again over the past months here and there, i did several searches but I couldn't if I remember right I think I used advanced circuits .ulp scripts.  I'll look again through my hdd's and see what comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.
I found a blog post that deprecated the OPL or CPL parts numbers in favor of the more universal Manufacturer Part Number.

I solved it with the following steps:

- From the schematic view click  File > 'Run ULP...'
- Select bom.ulp

[image: ULP list with BOM.ULP]

- Export a CSV with all values
- Open it in Excel or import it into Google Sheets
- Edit it to match [the BOM template on SEEED Fusion](https://statics3.seeedstudio.com/assets/file/fusion/BOM_Template_2017_06_30.csv). This entails deleting most of the columns, as the Seeed BOM format is very simple. 
  [image: SEED BOM Template]
- Note that Seeed only cares about MPN (Manufacturers Part Number) Which might be in a different column on your auto-generated BOM depending on where your library